# UPDATE query with OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

i'm using cursor to loop through a self join table.
the query that i use to declare the cursor works fine - as for to return the correct row.
but when i try to update, i'm getting:

> One or more FOR UPDATE columns have been adjusted to the first instance of their table in the query.

thank you.

**EDIT:**
i managed to solve it by using Set-Based sql.
much quicker...
instead of looping the result set of the cursor and then update, i'm updating in the query body.

Comment: Any exemplary code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered above.
i managed to solve it by using Set-Based sql.